# search URL in not working on live

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

Iam developing a cart using opencart and I followed

[**SEO SEARCH URLS**](http://www.think-lamp.com/2012/02/se-optimized-search-url-for-opencart-search/)

for changing the result URL from top search form.And it worked perfectly on my localhost.But after I uploaded those files to live ,it is not working even it throughs me a error like

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ControllerProductSearch::ajax() in /home/myopencart/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_product_search.php on line 744.
```

Can anyone suggest me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming in ControllerProductSearch you have more then one function called ajax.

There might be a couple of different files called vq2-catalog_controller_product_search.php and the new site may be picking up a different version then what is intended because of differences in include paths. That may explain why it is working in one environment and not the other.

I noticed two that it is being pulled from a vqcache directory, could vqmod need a cache refresh.

To refresh the cache you simply delete the /vqmod/mods.cache file

Comment: Excellent......I have 2 ajax functions.....in vq2-catalog_controller_product_search.php file...I have removed and working fine....thanku....

Comment: But even I delete ajax function after page refresh it is not wotrking

Comment: And also how to refresh cache..??

Comment: you should be able to refresh the cache by deleting `/home/myopencart/public_html/vqmod/mods.cache`

Comment: but there is no such a file @Orangepill

Comment: [This](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=47269) should provide you with a couple of methods of clearing the cache.

Comment: This problem is only from cache only..??bec each time I deleting second ajax function at live and after refresh it again occurs second time

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue... try disabling the vqmod cache (previously supplied link showed how to do that).